# Import folder that begins with a decimal

Tags: python, import

Following [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33143646/10734452), how do you do when your application folder start with a decimal (for instance : 00_build, 01_run, 02_parseResult)?

I get the following error:
`From 01_run.foo import bar`

> SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal

I tried this
`From '01_run'.foo import bar`

> SyntaxError: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Python identifiers, including modules, cannot start with a digit. You can play with `__import__` and other stuff, but it's bad practice anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `importlib` may be what you need:

```
import importlib
foo = importlib.import_module('01_run.foo')
bar = foo.bar
```

The reason why you can get `bar` in this way is that:

> The most important difference between these two functions is that `import_module()` returns the specified package or module (e.g. pkg.mod), ...

It also works in the Py2 environment, provided that the `01_run` is a Py2 module. You may need to add a `__init__.py` under the folder `01_run` if it doesn't exist before.

Read [the official page of `importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) for more details if you use Py3, read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) instead if you use Py2.

Comment: that is what i though but i have issue then importing globals from it... anyway i think this is the solution, ty